# parameters re not passed in react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am struggling with passing parameters via navigation. The parameters are always undefined.
Using version 4.

From the class Userlist I want to navigate to the GameplayScreen. I am passing a parameter there, but it never arrives.

```
export default class Userlist extends React.Component {


  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.fbUser = new FBUser();
    this.state = {
      lastRefresh: '',
    }
  }

  ...

  handleTouchUser = (item) => {
     ...

     // parameter passing does not work!
     this.props.navigation.navigate({ routeName: 'GameplayScreen', params: { itemId: '90' } });
  }
   ...
```

In the GameplayScreen class I try to read the parameter like this:

```
export default class GameplayScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      alert(this.props.navigation.getParam('itemId'));
      ...
  }
```

I have a [github repos](https://github.com/toki79/PlainScrabble/blob/master/Screen/drawerScreens/GameplayScreen.js) where the whole code can be seen.

Comment: can you try this.props.navigation.navigate( 'GameplayScreen',{ itemId: '90' }); ?

Comment: Yes, that doesn't change anything..